# Borders and spacing between specific table rows

Tags: css, html-table, row, border, margin

I am new to CSS and am working on an intraweb application which will render in modern standard browsers (IE support is *not* necessary).  I have spent much time looking for answers on this and other sites, only to find the answers "It's impossible because..." or "Do this hack instead...." but I just won't accept that.

**Here's what I need:**

1. A table with one header row and multiple body rows;
2. A solid border under the header row;
3. Vertical white space (padding? margin? spacing?) between the header row and first body row only;
4. Body rows being highlighted on mouse hover.

I couldn't get (2) to be visible until I styled the table `border-collapse: collapse;`.   Fine.  But (3) apparently only works with `border-spacing`, and only on `<td>` elements (not `<tbody>` or `<tr>`), which is anyway disabled by the `collapse`.  Meanwhile, for some unknowable reason, `margin`'s are not recognized for `<thead>`, `<tr>`, or `<th>` elements, but having `padding-top` on the first row of the body's `<td>`'s works, except it doesn't, because when I mouse over that first row, the whole margin-which-is-implemented-as-`padding` gets highlighted as well, which nauseates me.

I know having a few pixels of margin between a table's header and body is like a really out-of-left-field, why-would-anyone-ever-want-that thing to want, but what should I tell you? I'm no cheap date.

Please be as brutal and condescending as you can in pointing out my stupidity in understanding CSS, *provided you also* either 1) say how to do it without changing the markup (thereby preserving the separation of presentation from content CSS was evidently designed to encourage) or 2) agree with me that CSS is weird.

```
<head><style>
  table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
  }
  thead {
    border-bottom: 4px solid #123456;
  }
  /*** something goes here ***/
  tbody tr:hover {
    background-color: #ABCDEF;
  }
</style></head>

<body>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr><th>Fruit</th><th>Color</th><th>Yummy?</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr><td>Apple</td><td>Green</td><td>Yes</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Banana</td><td>Yellow</td><td>Yes</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Pear</td><td>Brown</td><td>Yes</td></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

This would fix your problems without any hacks and ofcourse its completely possible. The updated code(only CSS changes) is shared below with explanations.

**Problem 3** :

We can make use of the CSS selector `:first-of-type`(targeting only the first row) in succession with all the `<td>` under it and use attribute `padding-top`. Simple :-)

`<tr>` cannot have margin values by default. Again hacks are available(above mentioned answers) but I wouldn't go there as you don't want it.

And also since we have used `padding`, the hover effect would work perfectly on the entire row content. Hence getting the desired change without any markup changes.

**Problem 2** :

We can remove the attribute `border-collapse` from `table` and instead apply the border on the `<th>`tags (let the `border-spacing: 0` remain or the border would be discontinuous). Simple again :-)

**Problem 1 and 4** are already covered. No markup changes as you wished. [Here is the Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0qfj7gzu/)

So the updated style code would look like

```
<head><style>
  table {
    border-spacing: 0;
  }
  thead tr th {
    border-bottom: 4px solid #123456;
  }
  tbody tr:hover {
    background-color: #ABCDEF;
  }

  /*** added ***/
  tbody tr:first-of-type td {
    padding-top: 10px;
  }

</style></head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, in order:

**1:** A table with one header row and multiple body rows:

This is what the elements `thead` and `tbody` were designed for:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr><th>heading one</th><th>Heading two</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <!--
            all body table rows in here
        -->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

There's also `tfoot` (see references), which, if used, must be declared *before* the `tbody` element.

**2:** A solid border under the header row:

```
    thead tr th {
        border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
    }
```

Select the `th` elements within the `thead` element, the `tr` selector is probably unnecessary here, and, while it does no harm, can be simplified to: `thead th {/*...*/}`.

**3:** Vertical white space (padding? margin? spacing?) between the header row and first body row only. `padding`, it seems, cannot be applied to the `thead`, `tbody` or `tr` elements, since they're, essentially (I suppose) 'non-visual', so it has to be defined on the `td` elements. This does, on hover, mean there's a disconcertingly large 'row' occupied by the first row during the `:hover` (see the next part).

```
    tbody tr:first-child td {
        padding-top: 1em;
    }
```

**4:** Body rows being highlighted on mouse hover.

```
    tbody tr:hover td {
        background-color: #ffa;
    }
```

While you can apply a `:hover` to the currently-hovered cell, and later siblings (with the general sibling `~` combinator) you can't apply a style to siblings that appear previously, so here we're styling the `td` elements in response to the `:hover` of their parent `tr`.

The reason that we have to style the `td` (rather than directly change the `background-color` of the `tr` is because `td` elements don't typically default to a transparent background, which means the changed/highlighted `background-color` is 'hidden' by the `background-color` of the `td` elements.

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/9bkN2/).

References:

- [Table row-groups, `thead`, `tbody`, `tfoot` elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.3).

Comment: Narrow it down a little for me: what doesn't work? All of it? Just some of it? What browser/OS are you using? Ah; okay, how about [this hack](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/9bkN2/1/).

Comment: Thanks.  That works.  I'm not going to mark the answer as accepted, though, because it's a hack.  As I said in my question, CSS is supposed to separate presentation from content, and using CSS to insert blank content into a webpage to hack whitespace seems somehow worse than when people just used HTML for that.  Unless someone can make a reasoned argument to the contrary, I have to think this is not a good practice.

Comment: It's not perfect, no. I'd perhaps suggest adding an empty `tbody` and/or `tr`, like [this, for example](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/9bkN2/2/). But, it seems, that whatever happens there's going to have to be a 'hack' of some kind. Perhaps only because of current incomplete implementations.

Comment: I don't agree that using positioning is a hack. It does exactly what it is supposed to - position the elements on the page the way you want it, otherwise table will behave as it was intended by the w3c - it is a solid block with no whitespace between rows.

Comment: @KonstantinLevin Neither positioning nor David Thomas's above examples work, the former for the reasons mentioned in my comment below, and the latter because it just covers up the padding with solid color, which I can't do because I've got a background gradient there.  Thanks anyway for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In order to apply `margin` to the first table row you need to make it `display: block;` first, as margin can only be applied to block elements (including inline-blocks)

But here is another solution using positioning:

```
<head><style>
  table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    position: relative; /* Add positioning */
    margin-top: 40px; /* Add some margin */
  }
  thead {
    border-bottom: 4px solid #123456;
  }
  /*** something goes here ***/
  thead {
    position: absolute; /* Position this element absolute */
    top: -40px;  /* And move it up */
  }
  tbody tr:hover {
    background-color: #ABCDEF;
  }
</style></head>

<body>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr><th>Fruit</th><th>Color</th><th>Yummy?</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr><td>Apple</td><td>Green</td><td>Yes</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Banana</td><td>Yellow</td><td>Yes</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Pear</td><td>Brown</td><td>Yes</td></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <p>Thats how its done!</p>
</body>
```

Basically we apply `position: relative;` to the table and `position: absolute;` to thead.
Now you can move the thead inside the table using `top`, `bottom`, `left` and `right` properties. We are going to move it up by 40px using `top: -40px;`
We do not apply `position: absolute;` to tbody, because if we do - this element will no longer 'strech the page' or in other words all the following elements will ignore its height. (try doing it and see what happens to the following

block)
The only thing we got left - is to apply some margin-top to the table itself, moving it down (as we moved the thead up)

Yes, CSS can seem a bit weird from time to time, but this is mostly because we forget how some page elements are supposed to be handled (namely tables and their child elements)

Comment: I tried your example.  Then I tried styling all `<tr>` elements with `display: block; margin-bottom: 20px;`.  All my columns were out of vertical alignment.  There must be something about `display: block;` which messes with table alignment.  But at least `margin` now works.

Comment: Well block elements are supposed to go to the next 'line', so you can change that to `inline-block` in order to keep them on a single one.
Actually, I found another quick solution using positioning, I'll update my answer in a minute.

Answer (score 0):

What about adding an empty row at the beginning like

```
<tbody>
    <tr><td> </td></tr>
    <tr><td>blablablabla</td></tr>
```

And use this CSS

```
tbody tr:first-child td{
    padding-top: 15px;
}
tbody tr:first-child:hover{    
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

So the padding will be added to first row and first row won't highlight on mouse over? :)

Answer (score -1):

All your 4 points are covered there-

1. First download metro ui css here http://metroui.org.ua/
2. Include its two css file 1. metro-bootstrap, 2.metro-bootstrap-responsive  into your project.
3. Register that in BundleConfig.

   bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css/metroUI").Include("~/Content/css/metro-bootstrap.css",
              "~/Content/css/metro-bootstrap-responsive.css"));
4. Now use class "gr-items" for table

< table id="divAllActivities" class="gr-items">

```
<thead>
    <tr><th><span>Comment</span></th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><span>OperationDateTime</span></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td><span>OperationDateTime</span></td>
     </tr>
</tbody>
```

Hope this is what you want.

Comment: this explains nothing. And your solution needs markup changes ("say how to do it without changing the markup"). I think you should avoid Frameworks if you want to understand such issues as stated above. You should rather try reducing your code instead of expanding it with overblown extra css if you are looking for a clean solution